# AdMob and Analytics in same app

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob

I have AdMob and Analytics, each tutorial requested me to add to gradle file. But do I really need both?:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0` contains the other. But it also contains lots of other Google libraries.

You probably want to either use Proguard to remove the unused libraries/classes or explicitly include:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
```